# Optimizing Report Generation Runtime Using fmt Library's fmt::output_file API

Tags: c++, fmt

**Update**

I also ran a small program in c++ for usage of both, system fprintf and fmt::output_file API but still could not see any difference in the runtime.

**For c++ program using fprintf -**

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    const char* filename = "large_file.txt";
    const char* content = "Test";

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    FILE* fp = std::fopen(filename, "wb");
    if (!fp) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file: " << filename << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }   
    
    size_t iterations = 1e7;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        std::fprintf(fp, "%s", content);
    }   

    std::fclose(fp);

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << duration << " ms" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

```
Output - 
[anhad fmt_tests]$ ./output_bench1 
Elapsed time: 319 ms
[anhad fmt_tests]$
```

**For c++ programme using fmt::output_file API**

```cpp
#include "fmt/core.h"
#include "fmt/os.h"
#include "fmt/ostream.h"
#include "fmt/printf.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main() {
    const char* content = "Test";

    const size_t bufferSize = 653539;
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    fmt::ostream out = fmt::output_file("filename.txt", fmt::buffer_size= bufferSize);
  
    size_t iterations = 1e7;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        out.print("{}", content);
    }

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << duration << " ms" << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output -

```
[anhad fmt_tests]$ ./output_fmt_bench
Elapsed time: 1745 ms
[anhad fmt_tests]$
```

Both the files which were populated have the same size -

```
[anhad fmt_tests]$ du -sh large_file.txt filename.txt
39M large_file.txt
39M filename.txt
[anhadp fmt_tests]$
```

**Greetings,**

I want to share a technical exploration I recently undertook in my C++ program aimed at **enhancing the efficiency of the programme's runtime**.

We were using fprintf to write to a file and sprintf for character conversion.

However, for performance improvement, I integrated the `fmt` library (version 10) into my C++ project. fmt::output_file API in place of fprintf and fmt::format_to API in place of sprintf My attention was particularly drawn to the `fmt::output_file` API, which promised a substantial runtime enhancement of 5-9 times compared to the conventional `fprintf` approach. To my intrigue, though, the anticipated performance gain was not readily evident in my runtime measurements.

1. **File Opening:**
   I initiated the file for writing within a separate function using the `fmt::ostream` class along with the `fmt::output_file` API. The code snippet appeared as follows:

```cpp
fmt::ostream out = fmt::output_file(filename, fmt::buffer_size);
```

The `out` object created through this approach was subsequently passed by reference to other functions.

2. **Buffer Size Control:**
   I introduced a level of configurability to the buffer size by employing an environment variable. The snippet below demonstrates the dynamic adjustment of the buffer size based on the environment variable `BUFFER_SIZE`:

```cpp
static int bufferSize = (bufferSizeEnv != nullptr) ? std::stoi(bufferSizeEnv) : 16384;
```

This enabled me to fine-tune the buffer size according to the specific needs of my application.

Despite setting up the `fmt::output_file` API and configuring the buffer size with different values ranging from `4k to 65k`, I was surprised to find that there were **no runtime improvements**. The `fmt` library documentation suggested a significant boost, but I encountered a gap between the expected and observed outcomes.

Below is an example snippet of how this API was applied in my C++ code.

```cpp
FILE* outputFileApiFunc(string type, string outputfile ,fmt::ostream& out)
{
   FILE *fp = NULL;
   fp = std::fopen(outputfile.c_str(),"w");
 
    if(type == "one" || type == "two" || type == "three" || type == "all")
     out.print("\n type found = {}\n", func1.c_str());
    else
      out.print("\n{} type not found\n\n",func2.c_str());
    out.print("output is           = {}\n", outputFunc.c_str());
   
  return fp;
}
```

When used the `fmt::format_to` API and a `fmt::memory_buffer` of FMT version 10 in place of system sprintf, I could see a gain of **10 mins** in my runtime.

Below is an example snippet of how this `fmt::format_to` API was applied in my C++ code.

```cpp
{
  fmt::memory_buffer bufferString;
File* fp = NULL;

case name:
            fmt::format_to(std::back_inserter(bufferString),"{:<15} ", "Dave");
            break;
case age:
            fmt::format_to(std::back_inserter(bufferString),"{:<30} ", 17);                                    
             break;

fmt::print(fp,bufferString.data());
}
```

**So there was improvement in fmt::format_to API only and this result was expected from the output_file API as well.**

Perhaps there are subtleties or bottlenecks that I might have overlooked. If any of you have experienced a similar phenomenon or possess an in-depth understanding of the inner workings of the `fmt` library, your expertise would be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are comparing a debug version of {fmt} with an optimized version of printf (since it is a part of the system C runtime).

Compiling your code on macOS with clang the {fmt} program is ~2x faster:

{fmt}:

```
% c++ -O2 -DNDEBUG -I include test-fmt.cc src/format.cc src/os.cc -std=c++17
% time ./a.out
Elapsed time: 142 ms
./a.out  0.14s user 0.01s system 34% cpu 0.431 total
```

printf:

```
% rm filename.txt
% c++ -O2 -DNDEBUG test-printf.cc -std=c++17
% time ./a.out
Elapsed time: 298 ms
./a.out  0.25s user 0.05s system 54% cpu 0.558 total
```

The choice of the buffer size is questionable too. It should normally be a multiple of the page size.

Based on the investigation from this GitHub issue: https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/issues/3576.